# Searching for groups of rows where a column contains ALL given values

Tags: mysql

I have a table `symptom_ratings` containing the columns `id`, `user_id`, `review_id`, `symptom_id`, `rate`, and `strain_id`.

Each review can have multiple entries in `symptom_ratings`, one per symptom.

I would like to do a search for every `strain_id` that has all of the `symptom_id`'s the user searches for.

That is, given the columns:

```
review: 2, strain_id: 3, symptom_id: 43  
review: 2, strain_id: 3, symptom_id: 23  
review: 2, strain_id: 3, symptom_id: 12

review: 6, strain_id: 1, symptom_id: 3  
review: 6, strain_id: 2, symptom_id: 12
```

Searching for the `symptom_id`'s 43 and 12 should only return results for `strain_id` 3.

I currently use the following `WHERE` condition:

```
Strain.id IN (SELECT strain_id
    FROM symptom_ratings
    WHERE symptom_id
    IN ($symptoms))
```

where `$symptoms` is a comma-separated list of `symptom_id` values.

My problems is that this query currently performs an OR search (i.e. it finds strains that have *any* of the symptoms), where instead I'd prefer an AND search (i.e. finding strains that have *all* of the symptoms). How can I achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I have edited your question to make it easier to read. I recommend taking a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how to ask a proper question, there are still some things that can be done to make the question more appropriate to the platform. Good luck.

Comment: You should remove the PHP part all together since it's not really related to the question and just stick to the SQL part -- which is missing the SELECT keyword in your case. If you don't feel comfortable with that then you should at least show the related code, e.g. `$symptoms` and the initialization of `$condition`, and tag the question accordingly. I hope I'm making myself clear.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to group the rows by the strain ID, count the number of distinct matching symptoms in each group, and return only those rows where the count equals the total number of symptoms searched for:

```
SELECT
    strain_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT symptom_id) AS matched_symptoms
FROM symptom_ratings
WHERE symptom_id IN (43, 12)
GROUP BY strain_id
HAVING matched_symptoms = 2
```

[Here's a quick online demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d6c7/3/0)

One potentially useful feature of this method is that it's trivial to extend it to support both "all of these", "any of these" and "at least *n* of these" searches just by changing the condition in the `HAVING` clause.  For the latter cases, you can also sort the results by the number of matching symptoms (e.g. with `ORDER BY matched_symptoms DESC`).

Comment: BTW, if you also want a list of the matched symptoms, you can get that by adding e.g. `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT symptom_id) AS symptom_list` to the column list.